# SpringBoot and JSON using PUT

Tags: json, spring-boot, put

I'm facing a little situation using SpringBoot and a PUT request. All is working fine concerning GET. I try to send a PUT request passing an object as JSON (testing using postman).
Maven configuration:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Here is my POJO:

```
public final class Request
{
   private String name;
   private Boolean lock;

   //...public getter and setters...
}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class Controller
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "locking", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public static synchronized Object lock(Request request)
    {
        System.out.println("name:"+request.getName());
        System.out.println("lock:"+request.getLock());
        return null;
    }
}
```

My input is (using postman):

```
http://localhost:8080/controller/locking
request type: PUT
Content-Type: application/json
Content:{"name":"test","lock":true}
```

My output is:

```
name:null
lock:null
```

Again a simple GET works just fine.

Any idea on what I'm missing here?

Comment: You are missing @RequestBody annotation before method parameter type

Comment: Good :) Thanks a lot.